# android Dialog inside TabHost's activity

Tags: android, android-activity, dialog, tabs

Here is the issue i am having. i have a tab host with 4 tab activities.
I want to show a simple progress dialog in one of my activities but made so that the user can still move through the rest of the tabs (clicking the tabWidget should be still possible and the dialog will only show on the one activity). is something like this possible?

please help.
thanks.

Comment: i have tried inserting the dialog in the subactivity. and it appears but it is actually on top of the tabhost, not just inside the activity that launched it.

Comment: can you share your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it inside only one activity, use a [PrograssBar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html) instead of a dialog. Add it to your layout as with any other View.

Comment: yeah i know this is possible. i was also considering adding an empty view because the activity contains a gridview. but i am still considering the alternatives to making something like that.

Comment: @DArkO I tend to consider the simplest option as the best one. If you're GridView is inside a RelativeLayout, it is extremely simple to add the bar at the place you want in the screen (center? bottom?) and draw it on top of your GridView. When done, you simple remove the View (or set it to GONE)

Comment: yeah i agree with you here but a progressbar in my opinion doesn't really say dont touch.

Comment: @DArkO That's true. Would `gridView.setEnabled=false;` work for you?

Comment: well i would still prefer the empty view in the grid with a progress bar.